# Texmaker jumps to the "wrong" position

Tags: texmaker, input

I'm writing a bigger document right now. Because of that I have "exported" each chapter. So my document.tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{article}
\begin{document}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1} % Introduction1
\input{Chapters/Chapter2} % Introduction2
\input{Chapters/Chapter3} % Introduction3
\input{Chapters/Chapter4} % Introduction4
\end{document}
```

There's no problem by compiling this now, but when I press "View PDF" it jumps always to the first page. Is there a possibility to make sure that it jumps to the place where the last change was made? This happened as I was not importing all the chapters, but have them in one big file.

I'm using Texmaker in Windows 10.

Comment: anyone any ideas?